# Node.js forgets it's been installed?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, node.js

I installed node via nvm on a fresh ubuntu 14.04 system. Everything worked great. Next day I boot up and node isn't installed:

```
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I try 'nvm install stable' and get:

```
v0.12.5 is already installed.
Now using node v0.12.5 (npm v2.11.2)
```

which works fine (as far as I can see) until the next reboot. I've tried all the obvious 'nvm use ####' and remove/reinstall. No effect.

How do I make the install stick across a reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to setup a default version of node to be available globally.

`nvm alias default v0.11.13`

I suggest running `nvm use stable`, then doing `node --version` and then setting your default to the latest stable version